# Expectation of the product of an exponential random variable and an indicator random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given $X,Y$ are independent exponentially distributed random variables with parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$.

How do i find $E[X\cdot 1_{\{X<Y\}}]$?

If it's $E[XY]$, then i can attain the joint distribution function and then apply the definition of Expectation. But for this case, im totally clueless. Please help me :(

Comment: Hint: not only $E[X Y] = \int \int x y f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx dy$ but also
$$E[g(X Y)] = \int \int g(x,y) f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx dy$$

Comment: How do i find the joint probability function? Exponential random variable is continuous but Indicator random variable is discrete.

Comment: NO, the indicator  function is a function of continuous $X,Y$

Comment: I suppose the indicator random variable only takes value $0$ and $1$?

Comment: Yes, so? That's still a function of continuos variable (it just takes a discrete set of values, that does not matter).

Comment: :O i see, for example, $1_{\{X<\infty\}}$ is a random variable that is a function of $X$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64773/discussion-between-little-rookie-and-leonbloy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

$$E[g(X ,Y)] = \iint g(x,y) f_{X,Y}(x,y) dx dy$$

Noting that $X,Y$ are independent, and using the function $g(x,y)=x\cdot 1_{\{x<y\}}$ we get

$$\begin{align}
E(X\cdot 1_{\{X<Y\}})&=\iint x \, 1_{\{x<y\}} f_X(x) f_Y(y) dx dy\\ 
&=\int \int_{x<y} x  f_X(x) f_Y(y)  dx dy  \\ 
&= \int_0^{\infty} x  f_X(x)\int_x^{\infty}  f_Y(y)  dy dx
\end{align}$$